# set template table td bgcolor in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to set table cells to different background colors in a django front end page pop up. The pop up comes back from a view after a jquery call. An extract of the code follows:

```
<tr>
 <th>mySideHeader</th>  
 {% for key in FDI %}
   <td bgcolor={{key.1}}> {{key.0}}</td>
 {% endfor%}
</tr>
```

I get a valid value for both key.0 and key.1; key.1 is a color coding that changes depending on the value of key.0 from green to red and colors in between. However all my cell bgcolors look like the django default light blue color. How can I override this in the template?

When I run a direct url to get to the view via a browser I can see the bgcolor comes back correctly;but when I run this normally by clicking on the site the django default colors come into play.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that bgcolor is depracated in html 5. So by using an inline style I could get the background color to vary according to the given {{key.1}} in the django template.